# Group By Sum Case subquery unnecessary linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have the following expression in linq

```
db.Produto.Where(x => db.ProdutoGroup
    .GroupBy(y => new { y.idProduto })
    .Select(y => y.Key.idProduto).Contains(x.id))
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.composicao, x.atributos, x.idTipoProduto })
    .Select(x => new {
        qtdeProdutos = x.Count(),
        idProduto = x.Max(y => y.id),
        liberadosVenda = x.Sum(y => y.flagLiberadoVenda == true ? 1 : 0),
        valoresValidados = x.Sum(y => y.flagValoresValidados == true ? 1 : 0)
    }).ToList();
```

And it generates the following code sql

[image]

But that way, it gets 3 times slower than this sql statement that returns me the same thing, how to make linq generate this query?

[image]

Comment: Why not try  `x => db.ProdutoGroup.Select(y => y.idProducto).Contains(x.Id)` for that first `Where`.  Personally I'd do `Where [Extent1].[id] in (Select idProducto From vw_producto_group)` for the SQL.  Or maybe `x => db.ProductoGroup.Any(y => y.idProducto == x.Id)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to put a Where that justifies the existence of the group by on the ProdutoGroup, it is not currently in my code for tests, but this structure is essential for the operation of my query.

Comment: Even with a where there's no need for a group by or distinct.